# Django queryset union appears not to be working when combined with .annotate()

Tags: django, django-queryset

I have the following queryset:

```py
photos = Photo.objects.all()
```

I filter out two queries:

```py
a = photos.filter(gallery__name='NGL')
b = photos.filter(gallery__name='NGA')
```

I add them together, and they form one new, bigger queryset:

```py
c = a | b
```

Indeed, the length of `a + b` equals `c`:

```py
a.count() + b.count() == c.count()
>>> True
```

So far so good. Yet, if I introduce a `.annotate()`, the `|` no longer seems to work:

```py
a = photos.annotate(c=Count('label').exclude(c__lte=4)
b = photos.filter(painting=True)
c = a | b
a.count() + b.count() == c.count()
>>> False
```

How do I combine querysets, even when `.annotate()` is being used? Note that query one and two both work as intended in isolation, only when combining them using `|` does it seem to go wrong.

Comment: I believe you're experiencing an open ticket on the django bug tracker https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/26019

Comment: @Jason That seems to be it. Thank you, I was unable to find the ticket.

Comment: A way to see the difference is by checking the SQL.  You can print the query that is executed in django. For example, `c = a | b` and `print(c)` will display the SQL generated by Django.  You can then run the query in the shell and identify the differences to see _why_ the issue is happening.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

the pipe `|` or ampersand `&` to combine querysets actually puts `OR` or `AND` to SQL query so it looks like combined.

```
one = Photo.objects.filter(id=1)
two = Photo.objects.filter(id=2)
combined = one | two

print(combined.query)
>>> ... WHERE ("photo_photo"."id" = 1 OR "photo_photo"."id" = 2)...
```

But when you combine more filters and excludes you may notice it will give you strange results due to this. So that is why it doesn't match when you compare counts.

If you use `.union()` you have to have same columns with same data type, so you have to annotate both querysets. Info about `.union()`

> - SELECT statement within .UNION() must have the same number of columns
> - The columns must also have similar data types
> - The columns in each SELECT statement must also be in the same order

You have to keep in mind, that pythons argument `kwargs` for indefinite number of arguments are dictionary, so if you want to use annotate with multiple annotations, you can't ensure correct order of columns. Fortunatelly you can solve this with chaining annotate commands.

```
 # printed query of this won't be consistent
 photo_queryset.annotate(label_count=Count('labels'), tag_count=Count('tags')) 
 # this will always have same order of columns
 photo_queryset.annotate(label_count=Count('labels')).annotate(tag_count=Count('tags'))
```

Then you can use `.union()` and it won't mess up results of annotation. Also `.union()` should be last method, because after `.union()` you can't use `filter` like methods. If you want to preserve duplicates, you use `.union(qs, all=True)` since `.union()` has default `all=False` and calls `DISTINCT` on queryset

```
photos = Photo.objects.annotate(c=Count('labels'))
one = photos.exclude(c__lte=4)
two = photos.filter(painting=True)
all = one.union(two, all=True)
one.count() + two.count() == all.count()
>>> True
```

then it should work like you described in question