# Create custom Values method in django

Tags: django, django-managers

## I want to create a method semi to values method in Django QuerySet.

**The values method problems are:**

1. Miss order of fields in querySet if  I make **myquery = MyModel.objects.values('field1','field2','field3')**
   when I print querSet it **give me [{'field2':'data','field1':'data','field3':'data'},...]**. so this miss order will cause a problem at **Union** of queryset.
2. if the **field is choices** at model then **values(...) will give me the key of dictionary instead of its value**.

- **I want to create my custom values method using django Manager**

  ```
  class MyModelManager(models.Manager):
      def values(self, *fields):
          # I want to get model belong to this manger
          # then I want to check the fields if its in models (we have fields came from annotate)
          # after that I want to exclude to the fields that has choices 
          # next I want to call the super values method and passed to it the values that does not have choices
          # finally I want to reorder query according to passed fields

  class MyModel(models.model):
      # An example model
      objects = MyModelManager()
  ```

Comment: you can pass `named=True` and use `values_list ` instead of `values` with `queryset`. It will return `namedtuple` which may satisfy your use case.

Reference: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list

Comment: Why would the order of the keys in the returned dictionaries cause a problem with a `Union`?

Comment: Why not simply use the `get_<field_name>_display` method Django makes for each field with choices?

Comment: @lain  **union** ,the union is apply if and only if all queryset have the same order. you can read the Union conditions here [https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#union

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat you are right, but  I want to improve the performance instead of iteration around all queryset.

Comment: @AlASADWAIL Your problem with the union is not a problem at all. The union is done at the database side so the union will work properly there with the values. Dictionaries are not meant to be ordered so they will print in any order.

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat could you please use union in Django with annotate (additional fields). You will know what I mean.

Comment: @AlASADWAIL you need to annotate all your querysets for that also since kwargs are not ordered you need to **chain** the annotations if there are multiple [Django queryset union appears not to be working when combined with .annotate()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48028411/django-queryset-union-appears-not-to-be-working-when-combined-with-annotate)